# How to get Running Total in MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help on how to code this on MS Access SQL Query Builder

Get the Running total of the points like below
[image]

sum the pts that is older than the current date then check if there is a reduce pts and subtract that to the total **applicable only** to those older than the reduce pts and will return 0 if reduce is greater than current running.

I have no idea on how to get the reduce pts work

edited Question:

[image]

I just need to make the November 23 running to be 1 instead of 0.5

Comment: So are you saying that you want the running total, on a given date, to include the points up to _and including_ that day, minus the reduce points up to _but excluding_ that day?

Comment: as you can see the running data on November 17 is already 0 so the running total on 23 November should be 1 and Nov 24 should be 3. thanks you sir for your time

Comment: You've changed your data a bit and I don't follow what the problem is at this point.  It would be helpful if you could clarify whether you are rounding your data and also can the running balance go negative.

Comment: no the running data can't be a negative. if buy back is greater than running then the running data will be zero and the next points after the running is set to zero will be the actual points example on November 17 the running points is already 0 so the running on Nov 23 should be 1 instead of 0.5, I misread the flow my bad the problem isn't on the buy back on the Nov 24 it's because the pts on Nov 23 is not right that why I though that Nov 24 Data is incorrect

Comment: I'm afraid it is still not clear how I need to change my query.

Comment: the running computation is correct until November 17, the problem is @ 23/11/2017 Running it should be 1 and not 0.5 since the pts on that date is 1 and the running on 24/11/2017 should be 3 since pts is 4 so 1+4 = 5 and buyback is 2 so 5-2 = 3. I hope made it clear to you sir. I deeply apologies for confusing you and I am really grateful for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is via a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    [Emp ID], Date, Pts, Reduce,
    (SELECT IIF(SUM(IIF(t2.Pts IS NULL, 0, t2.Pts) -
                    IIF(t2.Reduce IS NULL, 0, t2.Reduce)) < 0, 0,
                SUM(IIF(t2.Pts IS NULL, 0, t2.Pts) -
                    IIF(t2.Reduce IS NULL, 0, t2.Reduce))
     FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.Date <= t1.Date) Running
FROM yourTable t1;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that amazing code, only one problem though I won't subtract if the the pts and reduce is at the same date

Comment: @AkamiKurai Your question never implied such logic.  Edit your question and tell us what the real problem is then.

Comment: The query works great, I just need make it also deduct the running with both pts and buy are in a same data. example row 1 is pts and row 2 is buy back but the both have the same dates

Comment: @AkamiKurai My query already takes the difference between `Pts` and `Reduce` on each line.  Maybe you can provide some data?