# Ms Access running sum with dates and order inside dates

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access to create a DB. I have different physical containers and I want to obtain the running sum of the liquid that has been added and taken out of the container to give the balance of the liquid inside the container.

The biggest problem is ordering liquid transactions. I have read lots of resources, and I found out one way of doing this is adding time to the dates so they can be ordered, but I am supposed to not use time, so I have decided to add a manual ordering number within a date which I am not sure is the best way of achieving this, but at least I can do the ordering.

The fields I have are:

```
-ContainerId
-DateTransaction
-OrderInDate
-Quantity
```

Quantity is "-" for withdrawal and "+" for additions, so if I can properly get a running total, I will get the balance.

I thought of adding OrderInDate as seconds to the Date to correctly order the data and I have written a query like this (qryInventoryTransactionsOrder):

```
SELECT ContainerId, Quantity, DateTransaction, OrderInDate,
DateAdd("s",OrderInDate,DateTransaction) AS Expr1,
DSum("Quantity","qryInventoryTransactionsOrder",
"[ContainerId]=" & [ContainerId] & " AND
[Expr1] <= #" & [Expr1] & "#") AS Balance
FROM InventoryTransactions
ORDER BY ContainerId, DateAdd("s",OrderInDate,DateTransaction);
```

This returns very interesting result like this :

| ContainerId | DateTransaction | OrderInDate | Quantity | Expr1 | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 29/05/2023 | 1 | -50 | 29/05/2023 00:00:01 | -50 |
| 1 | 31/05/2023 | 1 | 100 | 31/05/2023 00:00:01 | 50 |
| 1 | 31/05/2023 | 2 | 255 | 31/05/2023 00:00:02 | 305 |
| 1 | 01/06/2023 | 1 | -155 | 01/06/2023 00:00:01 |  |
| 1 | 01/06/2023 | 2 | -155 | 01/06/2023 00:00:02 |  |
| 1 | 01/06/2023 | 3 | 2500 | 01/06/2023 00:00:03 |  |
| 1 | 08/06/2023 | 1 | -500 | 08/06/2023 00:00:01 | 1995 |

As you will see "Balance" is correct for the first 3 lines, then it returns 3 empty results, and then 1995.

What am I doing wrong here or is there a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: I did a test with posted sample data and your query and it works. However, your dates are displayed as international structure. This might be an issue. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html. Consider calculating this in report using textbox RunningSum property and report Sorting & Grouping features. Why are you using a query as source for this calc instead of table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running total query in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936340/running-total-query-in-access)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688169/how-to-get-running-total-in-ms-access-query and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347778/trouble-making-a-running-sum-in-access-query#:~:text=If%20you%20create%20a%20report%2C%20there%20is%20a,eq2%20WHERE%20DatePart%20%28%22yyyy%22%2Ceq2.%20%5BEoL%5D%29%20%3C%3D%20DatePart%20%28%22yyyy%22%2Ceq1.

Comment: Your narrative is a bit confusing. You indicate a query name followed by SQL but that SQL cannot be in a query with that posted name. This must be another query object. It does work for me when I change query name to table name and repeat DateAdd expression in the DSum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say anything about recursive queries in MS Access.It is interesting.

Try this query, where DSum counts sum from main table.

```
SELECT ContainerId, Quantity, DateTransaction, OrderInDate
    ,DateAdd("s",OrderInDate,DateTransaction) AS Expr1
    ,DSum("Quantity","InventoryTransactions"
       ,"[ContainerId]=" & [ContainerId] 
        & " AND Format(DateAdd(""s"",OrderInDate,DateTransaction),""yyyyMMddhhmmss"") <= " 
      & format(DateAdd("s",OrderInDate,DateTransaction),"yyyyMMddhhmmss") & "") 
    AS Balance
FROM InventoryTransactions
ORDER BY ContainerId, DateAdd("s",OrderInDate,DateTransaction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can'1 concatenate the date value that simple. You must force a neutral format for the string expression of this:

```sql
SELECT 
    ContainerId, 
    Quantity, 
    DateTransaction, 
    OrderInDate,
    DateAdd("s",OrderInDate,DateTransaction) AS Expr1,
    DSum(
        "Quantity",
        "qryInventoryTransactionsOrder",
        "[ContainerId]=" & [ContainerId] & " AND [Expr1] <= #" & Format([Expr1], 'yyyy\/mm\/dd hh:\nn\:ss') & "#") AS Balance
FROM 
    InventoryTransactions
ORDER BY 
    ContainerId, 
    DateAdd("s",OrderInDate,DateTransaction);
```

Comment: I get "#Error" on the Balance column with this

Comment: It was the inner quotes - should be single-quotes. You should _not_ repeat the date calculation and  the format twice.

Comment: This looks much cleaner, but I still get "#Error". When I click the "#Error" on the query result,  I get an error message, I have created a screenshot for it:  https://ibb.co/80GKVzx . It is very interesting it does not seem to take into consideration the last "#", if I make it "##" to test, this goes into the string.

Comment: Weird. But I can't open the screenshot.